# server configuration error

Tags: apache

what does this address http://www.jasbf.com/ says i did not understand when i check my error log it says something like this

```
[Mon Jan 17 01:15:22 2011] [error] File does not exist: /public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jan 17 01:15:21 2011] [error]  File does not exist: /public_html/404.shtml
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Apache's `DocumentRoot` misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing files or file permissions are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

favicon.ico is the little image left of the url bar in firefox/internet explorer. Those (and many more) browsers are looking for this icon to display. That is where the upper error comes from.

In case a webserver cannot find a requested url; it needs to display an error. This particular error is also known on the web as a "404 (not found)" error. However; this is displayed as a regular html page. The 404.shtml is probably what the webbrowser wants to use as 404 page.